# android theme color

Tags: android, colors, android-theme

I'm trying to make themes, I have asked myself, Is it possible to give the different colors for the particular textview.

Example: In "Theme.One", I will like in the textview "Title" the color Green and textview "text1" the color Pink.

Themes.xml

```
  <style name="Theme.One" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:background">@color/Azur</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/Black</item>
        ...
      </style>
      <style name="Theme.Two" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:background">@color/Blue</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
        ...
      </style>
```

Interface.xml

```
 <TextView
        android:text="@string/Title"
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/text1"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

I hope to have well formulated the sentences, and Thanking you in advance for answer,

Aziza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the manifest:

```
  android:theme="@style/myTheme"
```

In res/values folder :

```
<style parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" name="myTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00ff00</item>
    <item name="android:dateTextAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
</style>
```

you can change the color ti different color and apply the  color for the textview.

```
 android:textColor="yourcolor"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have one style for the pink and another one for green. For example
for the green TextView:

```
  <TextView
    android:text="@string/Title"
    android:id="@+id/Title"
    android:textSize="25sp"
   style="@style/Colorgreen"
 />
```

and for the style you have

```
  <style name="Colorgreen">
       <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        </style>
```